# Curl: one-liner to test http/2 support

Tags: unit-testing, curl, http2

I'm currently writing an unit test to check if `http/2` is supported.

Is there a `curl` one-liner which checks if `http/2` is supported and outputs a response that is easy to parse?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

HTTP/2 supported:

```
$ curl -sI https://curl.se -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
2
```

HTTP/2 not supported (instead serving 1.1 in this case):

```
$ curl -sI http://curl.se -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
1.1
```

(curl 7.50.0 or later is required for this command line to work)

### HTTP/3

Since curl 7.88.1, *if you build curl to support HTTP/3*, the above one-liner can be extended to also check for HTTP/3 support like this:

```
$ curl -sI --http3 https://curl.se -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
3
```

Comment: It is giving me the following error:

curl: unknown --write-out variable: 'http_version'

Comment: Run with `-k` (`curl -ksI ...`) if you're testing a server with self-signed certs.

Answer (score 11):

Run

```
curl --version
```

and look for HTTP2 on the Features list

Comment: One-liner for this: `curl --version | grep -i http2`

Comment: The question is about http2 support for specific websites, not for curl itself!

Comment: The ask is here to check whether the website supports HTTP/2 or not. But not to check whether curl supports HTTP/2.

Answer (score 6):

Here you can find a [list of Tools for debugging, testing and using HTTP/2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tools-for-debugging-testing-and-using-http-2/).

Probably the easiest one from the command line is:

```
$ is-http2 www.cloudflare.com
```

But that requires `npm install -g is-http2-cli`

For testing using `curl` you may need to compile it using the [nghttp](https://nghttp2.org/) library, in macOS this can be done by using `brew` you could use:

```
$ brew install curl --with-nghttp2
```

And then you could use what @daniel-stenberg suggests in his answer

```
$ curl -sI https://curl.haxx.se -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
```

In where you will get a 2 if http2 is supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your answer also contains options using other tools, which is very useful. However since Daniel Stenberg's answer is more fitting to the original question, I'm going to accept his answer.

Comment: You know, @nbari is-http2 and curl output is different:  
  
    curl -sI https://curl.haxx.se  
    HTTP/2 200  
    server: Apache  
    ...  
  
    is-http2 https://curl.haxx.se:443  
    × HTTP/2 not supported by https://curl.haxx.se:443

Answer (score 4):

I used

```
curl -kvso /dev/null --http2 https://app.domain.com:443
```

which returned

```
...
> GET / HTTP/2
...
< HTTP/2 302
...
```

this is not checking if HTTP2 is supported, but check if HTTP2 actually works.

Comment: `-kvso /dev/null` is short form to more verbose option list: `--insecure --verbose --silent --output /dev/null` - I suggest to consult https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html and Ctrl+F those options there to see details.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do:

```
curl --http2 --head domain.com
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer doesn't work for h2c in the example I'm looking at. Instead use:

`curl --http2 -sI https://curl.se -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'`

Answer (score 0):

In mac, we can check the curl supported HTTP versions using the below command

```
curl --manual | grep "\-\-http" -A 10
```

--http0.9 -  Tells curl to be fine with HTTP version 0.9 response

--http1.0 - Tells curl to use HTTP version 1.0 instead of  using  its
internally preferred HTTP version.

--http1.1 - Tells curl to use HTTP version 1.1.

--http2 - Tells curl to use HTTP version 2.

--http3 - Tells curl to try HTTP/3 to the host in the URL, but fallback to earlier HTTP versions if  the  HTTP/3  connection  establishment fails. HTTP/3 is only available for HTTPS and not for HTTP URLs.

```
$ curl -sI --http1.0 https://example.com -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
1
```

```
$ curl -sI --http1.1 https://example.com -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
1.1
```

```
$ curl -sI --http2 https://example.com -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'
2
```

Since example.com is configured to support HTTP\1.0, HTTP\1.1 and HTTP\2, it responds with corresponding HTTP version based on the incoming request from curl.