# Enable HTTP/2 in CloudFront with S3 origin does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, http2

A few days ago I've enabled HTTP/2 in CloudFront with S3 origin but it does not work. It keeps using http1.1

```
curl --http2 "https://my.cdn.com
curl: (1) Unsupported protocol
```

I've tested with both TLS1 and TLSv1.2_2018. I'm using a custom URL (Route53) with SSL (certificate manager). My viewer protocol policy is Redirect HTTP to HTTPS. What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you have HTTP2 enabled on cloudfront, could it be that your curl package is old ? check here to confirm: https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

Answer (score 0):

That error message is saying that your version of curl doesn’t support HTTP/2 - not that your site doesn’t support HTTP/2.

This answer lists various other ways to test for HTTP/2 support: [How to check if website has http/2 protocol support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54091567/how-to-check-if-website-has-http-2-protocol-support)