# How to check, does my host supports http2 or not?

Tags: wordpress, https, hosting, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have created a wordpress site. But wordpress supports http1. How to check, does my host supports http2 or not? Also let me know the steps to enable it on my wprdpress site for performance optimization.

Note: I am using rest APIs

Answer (score 0):

https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test

relevant info from another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096671/2740997

Answer (score 0):

Except the KeyCDN service that @trev provided there is another option. You can execute the next command from terminal:

```
curl -v http://yourdomain.com
```

Where "*yourdomain.com*" is your actual domain name. In the output there is one line like this:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

And you will be able to see if the HTTP/2 support is enabled. Note that the HTTP code after "*HTTP/1.1*" part could be different.

Small note: HTTP/2 will be displayed as HTTP/1.2 in the console output.