# Using HTTP/2 with nginx Ingress on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

We have configured a cluster on GKE and installed nginx-ingress. Using our ingress rule it works, but I can't make it work with HTTP/2. We set the data information on the ConfigMap but it will always fallback to http/1.1. This exact setup was running fine on DigitalOcean. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Thanks

Install Nginx-Ingress

```
kubectl create ns ingress-nginx
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx
```

My Ingress file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "mylocalip"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-server
          servicePort: 80
      - backend:
          serviceName: default-server
          servicePort: 80
```

My ConfigMap data applied to nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress configmap

```
data:
  use-http2: "true"
```

**EDIT (05/11/2021):**

We changed the ingress to work with certificates, now we connect using HTTPS. But still, all connections are established using http/1.1

Hi, thanks for the reply. But I've changed my ingress to use cert-manager and LetEncrypt, below is the updated Ingress.

**INGRESS**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "myip"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.mydomain.com
    secretName: my-cert
  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myweb
          servicePort: 80
```

## EDIT 2 (05/14/2021)

Current version: 1.19.9-gke.1400
Test using curl and https://http2.pro/ (both indicate it's not available)

This same setup works using k8s on DigitalOcean.

Here are my install and config files:

## INSTALL INGRESS-NGINX

```
kubectl create ns ingress-nginx
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP=x.x.x.x
```

## INGRESS

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - test.mydomain.com
    secretName: my-cert
  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myweb
          servicePort: 80
```

## CONFIGMAP

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  name: nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress
data:
  proxy-buffering: "false"
  ssl-ciphers: EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA+SHA256:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!MEDIUM:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED
  ssl-protocols: TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
  ssl-redirect: "true"
  use-forward-headers: "true"
  use-http2: "true"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT

---

After further reproduction I've noticed that in the question there is a miss-match between the `NGINX Ingress controllers`.

There are 2 similarly named `Ingress` controllers:

- *[Github.com: NginxInc: Kubernetes Ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress)* - for this purpose let's name it: ***nginx-inc***
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)* - for this purpose let's name it: ***nginx***

This are 2 separate products where the differences are explained here:

- *[Github.com: NginxInc: Kubernetes Ingress: Docs: Nginx ingress controllers](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/nginx-ingress-controllers.md)*

Due to this `Configmap` key:

- `use-http2: "true"`

I've incorrectly assumed that we are talking about the ***nginx*** where in fact it was the ***nginx-inc*** (I've missed the link of `$ helm repo add`). This field is specific to the ***nginx*** and will not work with the ***nginx-inc***.

I've managed to find a way to enable the `HTTP/2` support with the ***nginx-inc***. Change:

- from: `use-http2: "true"`
- to: `http2: "true"`

More explanation can be found here:

- *[Docs.nginx.com: Nginx Ingress Controller: Configuration: Global configuration: Configmap resource: Listeners](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/#listeners)*

---

---

Below part is more of a general approach to the support of `HTTP/2` on `GKE` with `Ingress`.

> A side note!
>
> Even without the `tls` part in the `YAML` manifest it's possible to use `HTTPS` due to the `Fake Ingress Controller certificate`

---

As pointed in the following github issue:

> aledbf commented on 28 Mar 2019
>
> ---
>
> **NGINX does not support HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 at the same time on a cleartext (non-TLS) port.**
> That's the reason why it works only when HTTPS is used.
>
> -- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress nginx: Issue: HTTP2 support](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3938#issuecomment-477412149)*

As stated to enable `HTTP/2` you will need to have the tls part (certificate) configured in your `Ingress` resource.

Here you can find the documentation to help you with the process:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Examples: TLS termination](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/)*

---

I've used your setup on the `GKE` version `1.20.5-gke.2000` (the `Helm` part) and here is what I found.

Querying the external IP of your `Ingress` controller with `HTTP` request will allow you to use `HTTP/1.1`.

After I've configured the certificate to use with the `Ingress` resource (and domain name), I could get the response stating that I'm using `HTTP/2`:

You can check it with various measures like `cURL` or online `HTTP/2` test sites:

- `curl -v -k https://DOMAIN.NAME`

```sh
* Trying IP_ADRESS
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to DOMAIN.NAME ( IP_ADRESS) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
< <-- REDACTED --> 
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fa5b300e800)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: DOMAIN.NAME
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< <-- REDACTED --> 
< 
< <-- NGINX WELCOME SITE --> 
* Connection #0 to host DOMAIN.NAME left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

You can also go for more of a one line solution:

- `curl -k -sI https://DOMAIN.NAME -o/dev/null -w '%{http_version}\n'`

where the output should be `2`. More reference:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Question: Curl: one-liner to test http/2 support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51279606/12257134)*

---

Also, adding to whole answer on the modified part of the `Configmap` of your `nginx-ingress`:

```
data:
  use-http2: "true"
```

> #### use-http2
>
> Enables or disables HTTP/2 support in **secure connections**.
>
> -- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: Nginx configuration: Configmap: Use HTTP/2](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-http2)*

I'm not also sure about the usage of this annotation:

- `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "mylocalip"`

as it's valid only for the `Ingress` resource for GKE `Ingress` and not `ingress-nginx`.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Tutorials: Configuring domain name static IP](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip)*
- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited the question to include the new Ingress, it works with HTTPS fine but still only http/1.1.

Comment: @Humberto could you please tell what software are you using to check the `HTTP` version? Also could you please tell more about your `GKE` version?

Comment: upgrade to the latest release channel but still no success. I've edited the question with the full config files. Thanks

Comment: @Humberto, please take a look on now updated answer.

Comment: that was exactly the issue, didn't notice the different version.