# Hello everyone, how can I setup my nginx ingresses to use HTTP2 protocol instead of HTTP1.1?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, http2, ingress-controller

I am using Nginx-Ingress Controller on my GKE cluster. The nginx version is `1.23.2`

Comment: I doubt that nginx supports forwarding http2. Last time I checked, it did not have plans for supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

GKE has an option Using  HTTP/2 for load balancing with Ingress :

The connection from the load balancer proxy to your application uses HTTP/1.1 by default. If your application, running in a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) pod, is capable of receiving HTTP/2 requests, you configure the external load balancer to use HTTP/2 when it forwards requests to your application.This feature has some [HTTP/2  limitations](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#HTTP2-limitations) read before you begin.

For achieving this you need to create a Deployment, a Service, and an Ingress. You need to put a cloud.google.com/app-protocols annotation in your Service manifest to specify that the load balancer should use HTTP/2 to communicate with your application.

As mentioned above while creating service add `cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"my-port":"HTTP2"}'` , so that the cloud.google.com/app-protocols annotation specifies that my-port should use the HTTP/2 protocol.

Here is the [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-http2) which has yaml files and procedure for using HTTP/2 protocol.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work with Nginx-Ingress Controller. I am not using GCE ingress for my applications.

Comment: Here is a similar [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471377/using-http-2-with-nginx-ingress-on-gke), can you try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried updating my nginx-ingress controller by providing both in its configmap, still my domains aren't using `http2` protocol.
`use-http2: "true"`
`http2: "true"`